# Direct and indirect effects of spatial panel durbin model

Tags: r, panel-data, spatial-data

I'm asking about the estimation of direct, indirect, and total effects of spatial durbin panel data modeling. As far as I know, there is no direct package of doing the estimations. So I generate the spatial lag of independent variables myself. Here is the simple version of my code

```
# Generate the spatial lags:  
 dataS$JC_2dg_s <- slag(dataS$JC_2dg, listw = cont.listw)
 dataS$JD_2dg_s <- slag(dataS$JD_2dg, listw = cont.listw)
# Define the equation and make the estimation  
 eq0_1 <- TFR_2  ~  JC_2dg  + JD_2dg  + JC_2dg_s + JD_2dg_s + 
 FLFP2030  + FLFP2030_s + logGDP_r  + logGDP_r_s + expat_ratio  + expat_ratio_s + 
 hp1000  + hp_s 
 model1<-spml(eq0_1, data=dataS, listw=cont.listw, model="within", spatial.error="none",lag=T,           effect="twoway", rel.tol=2e-40)
 summary(model1)
## But then, how to get the effects? I try to do it manually:  
W.c <- as(as_dgRMatrix_listw(cont.listw), "CsparseMatrix")
beta_jc <- model1$coefficients[2] 
theta_jc <- model1$coefficients[4] 
beta_jd <- model1$coefficients[3]  
theta_jd <- model1$coefficients[5]

# Calculate rho * W  
rhoW <- model1$spat.coef * W.c    
# Identity matrix  
I <- Matrix::Diagonal(nrow(W.c))
# Calculate (I - rho * W)^(-1)  
inverse_matrix <- solve(I - rhoW)
# Calculate the direct impact of beta and theta using (I - rho * W)^(-1)(beta + W * theta)  
mateff_jc <- inverse_matrix *(beta_jc) + inverse_matrix %*% (W.c *theta_jc)
mateff_jd <- inverse_matrix *(beta_jd) + inverse_matrix %*% (W.c *theta_jd)

# Calculate the average direct effect and its standard error  
ade_jc <- mean(diag(mateff_jc))
se_ade_jc <- sd(diag(mateff_jc)) 
t_directjc <- ade_jc/se_ade_jc
p_directjc <- 2 * (1 - pt(abs(t_directjc), df = nrow(W.c) - 1))
ade_jd <- mean(diag(mateff_jd))
se_ade_jd <- sd(diag(mateff_jd)) 
t_directjd <- ade_jd/se_ade_jd
p_directjd <- 2 * (1 - pt(abs(t_directjd), df = nrow(W.c) - 1))`
```

But after checking some literature, I don't know if I made the calculation of standard errors correct, as some variance-covariance might be included in the function.

Comment: What is your question ... ??  Is it the last commented line in your code?

Comment: yes, i edit it to make it clear.

Comment: Im not sure this helps but maybe mixed effects model can help: https://m-clark.github.io/mixed-models-with-R/random_intercepts.html#running-a-mixed-model